# PCE Emacs gone haywire (and nearly useless) after updating SWIPL to 8.0.1-1 (and then to 8.1.0)

Tags: windows, installation, prolog, swi-prolog

## My predicament, in the shell of a nut

Hi, **I recently installed the 64-bit version of SWI-Prolog 8.0.1.1-1** (replacing 7.6.4, which I had installed several years before) on my **Windows 10** machine, and essentially, when I opened PCE Emacs afterwards, all the language-specific features were broken. Meaning, **I can edit and save files as normal, but the syntax highlighting, source navigation, etc commands do not work**... which means that I might as well be editing everything in Fundamental mode. I have never had any issues with PCE Emacs before, and I did not modify anything SWIPL-related before upgrading.

Since SWI-Prolog appears to work fine on its own, as long as nothing GUI-related comes into the picture, **I strongly suspect that the PCE library and/or XPCE has been corrupted somehow, or something is wrong with the registry and/or environment variables that are supposed to direct SWIPL to the correct source and compiled files**. Unfortunately, I'm not enough of a PCE wizard (yet!) to know how to confirm (or invalidate) that suspicion... and even if it turns out that my hunch is correct, I don't know what to do about it.

I'd really like to fix this because while I'm a real GNU Emacs aficionado, I like the convenience of being able to quickly edit Prolog source files and take advantage of some nifty features without having to bring out my full arsenal of finely-tuned Emacs gadgetry every time.

That being said, I really don't want to have to completely uninstall and reinstall SWI-Prolog, although I'm fairly confident that that would solve the problem. (And I certainly don't want to have to wipe my entire computer over this, in the event that even my best efforts to purge all traces of SWIPL from it do not suffice...)

**Have you encountered this type of problem (further info below) before, and/or do you know how to fix it?**

---

## Beyond the nutshell... (Further Background)

### Abnormalities encountered during the installation process

The installer for 8.0.1-1 failed to add SWIPL to the `PATH` due to an error that had something to do with the path being too long... I didn't think much of it, since I know how to edit the system variables myself, anyway.

### Problems I managed to fix (and how)

Once the installation was complete, I opened the newly installed 8.0.1-1 to see if there was anything out of the ordinary. I executed a few simple test queries and everything seemed fine... until I decided to try to use PCE Emacs to edit a source file. When I selected the menu item `File > Edit...`, the following error appeared in the terminal before SWI-Prolog crashed:

> pce_error(no_home)

I promptly typed out a Google search, surrounding this bizarre term in quotes; pretty much the only relevant result was the PCE source code on Github. I looked at the source and noticed that it seemed that it looked for a system environment variable called `PCEHOME`. I added this environment variable, pointing it to `C:\Program Files\swipl\xpce\`. I also added `C:\Program Files\swipl\bin` and `C:\Program Files\swipl\xpce\` to the `PATH` environment variable, for good measure.

When I re-opened `swipl-win.exe` and selected `File > Open`, PCE Emacs opened  the file for editing, as expected. However, it did not take long for me to realize that something was still terribly wrong.

### Problems I have not managed to fix

The first thing I noticed was that the syntax highlighting was obviously broken; the status line showed several arcane-looking errors in response to me clicking around the source. When I switched to CHR mode, some syntax highlighting occurred, but approximately half the buffer became highlighted with a magenta background following a delimiter (a square bracket, I believe), and indicated that there was a syntax error (although in reality, the code had no syntax errors).

I could find nothing on the internet regarding PCE Emacs syntax highlighting being on the fritz. It seemed that I was the only one in the history of SWI-Prolog that had encountered such a problem...

Seeing as the beginning of my woes coincided with the upgrade, I speculated that the problem might be a bug introduced by 8.0.1-1. Being the forward-thinking person that I am, I figured it couldn't hurt to try upgrading to the latest development version (8.1.0), rather than downgrade back to 7.6.4.

### The current state of things

As of this question's original post date, the bizarre syntax highlighting behavior has been replaced by a complete lack of syntax highlighting. The other language-specific features remain unchanged (that is, they do not work, at all). **In short, PCE Emacs is still riddled with exceptions, several of which I've listed below.**

I hope this is thorough enough, but if there is any more information I can supply that might aid in the diagnosis of the cause of these issues and/or in their resolution, just let me know and I'll do my best to add it here.

---

#### Some examples of various menu bar menu item actions and the resulting errors/warnings, grouped by menu:

FILE:

- Selecting menu item `File > Mode > chr` when a buffer containing some CHR rules (in addition to normal SWIPL code) is active causes PCE Emacs to at least highlight matching paren pairs, but still no syntax highlighting.
- Selecting menu item `File > Shell` opens an empty buffer named `*shell* [exited]` and causes the following to appear in the PCE Emacs status line:

  > sh: Process exit status -1
- Selecting menu item `File > Mode > prolog` (when not already in Prolog mode) causes (as expected) the following to appear in the PCE Emacs status line:

  > Switched to ``prolog'' mode

  ...however, no syntax highlighting or source interaction features are activated, and PCE Emacs exhibits no change in appearance or functionality.

BROWSE:

- Selecting menu item `Browse > Prolog Navigator` does nothing.
- Mousing over menu item `Browse > Source file...` causes the following to appear in the terminal:

  > ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: atomic_list_concat/2: Type error: `text' expected, found `prolog/boot' (a compound)
  >   ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: atomic_list_concat/2: Type error: `text' expected, found `prolog/boot' (a compound)
- Selecting menu item `Browse > Find Definition...` and then typing, for example, `d` into the ***Prolog predicate*** field, followed by the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to trigger completion, causes the following to appear in the terminal:

  > ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: sub_atom/5: Type error: `atom' expected, found `C'dict'' (a reserved_symbol_reference)
  >   ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: sub_atom/5: Type error: `atom' expected, found `C'dict'' (a reserved_symbol_reference)

COMPILE:

- Selecting menu item `Compile > Compile buffer` causes the following to appear in the status bar at the bottom of the PCE Emacs window:

  > compile_buffer command failed

PROLOG:

- Selecting menu item `Prolog > Check clause` causes the following to appear in the status bar at the bottom of the PCE Emacs window:

  > check_clause command failed
- Selecting menu item `Prolog > Edit exceptions...` causes the following:

  - (as expected) The appearance of the *Manage exception debugging* dialog.
  - The appearance of a dialog titled *SWI-Prolog warnings* and containing only a **Quit** button and a selectable list-type field, which contains the following item:

    > gui.pl:91: Goal (directive) failed: prolog_gui:register_directives

    This item links to line 91 in the file `gui.pl`, which is opened in a new buffer in PCE Emacs when the item is clicked on.
  - The appearance in the terminal of the following:

    > ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: sub_atom/5: Type error: `atom' expected, found `C'dict'' (a reserved_symbol_reference)
    >   ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: sub_atom/5: Type error: `atom' expected, found `C'dict'' (a reserved_symbol_reference)
    >   Warning: c:/program files/swipl/xpce/prolog/lib/trace/gui.pl:91:
    >   Goal (directive) failed: prolog_gui:register_directories
    >   % The graphical front-end will be used for subsequent tracing

PCE:

- Selecting menu item `PCE > Editpce...` and then selecting, for example, `emacs_prolog_mode` from the ***Behaviour|class*** dropdown menu causes PCE Emacs to open a blank buffer (in the case of `emacs_prolog_mode`, one titled `prolog_mode.pl`). I am fairly sure that `prolog_mode.pl` (the file, not the buffer) can't truly be empty.
- Selecting menu item `Pce > Spypce...` and then selecting, for example, `emacs_mode` from the ***Behaviour|class*** dropdown menu causes

  > ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: emacs_fundamental_mode ->spypce: Argument 1 (?): `behaviour*' expected, found `@emacs_mode_class/emacs_mode_class'
- Selecting menu item `Pce > Tracepce...` and then selecting, for example, `prolog_ide` from the ***Behaviour|class*** dropdown menu causes the following to appear in the terminal:

  > ERROR: [Thread pce] Unhandled exception: emacs_fundamental_mode ->tracepce: Argument 1 (?): `behaviour*' expected, found `@prolog_ide_class/class'

HELP:

- Selecting menu item `Help > Help on mode` does nothing.
- Selecting menu item `Help > Help` causes the following:

  - (as expected) The appearance of the PCE help dialog
  - The appearance of the following in the terminal:

    > [PCE warning: @142244788304/hlp_buffer: Illegal value in slot indent_tabs: class_default]
- Selecting menu item `Help > Describe function...` and then selecting, for example, `colourise_buffer` from the ***Command*** dropdown menu merely causes the following to appear in the terminal:

  > Warning: [Thread pce] No help for @142240619460/send_method.
  >   Warning: [Thread pce] Use ?- apropos(query). to search for candidates.

MISC:

- I don't remember what I did to cause this one, but the following error also appeared in the terminal:

  > ERROR: [Thread pce] @142240667182/dialog: No implementation for: <-mode
- I did a `make.` just now (I've done several already in this session, but this is the first time something like this happened as a result) and the following appeared in the terminal:

  > % Updating index for library c:/program files/swipl/library/
  >   %  settings compiled into trace_settings 0.00 sec, 0 clauses
  >   %  stack compiled into prolog_ide_stack 0.02 sec, 0 clauses
  >   %  viewterm compiled into prolog_term_view 0.02 sec, 0 clauses
  >   Warning: c:/program files/swipl/xpce/prolog/lib/trace/gui.pl:91:
  >           Goal (directive) failed: prolog_gui:register_directories
  >   % c:/program files/swipl/xpce/prolog/lib/trace/gui compiled into prolog_gui

  I'm guessing it has something to do with the files I opened via `Pce > Tracepce`, etc... But I did not make any changes to any of the files. Additionally, every time I do a `make` it takes longer than I'd expect, and it always shows `Updating index for library c:/program files/swipl/library/`, even if I do two `make.`s in a row...

Comment: I recently uninstalled SWI-Prolog 7.x to to upgrade to 8.x and had both 32 and 64-bit versions on my machine. I am sure that took less time than it took to write this question. Just do it and be done with it.

Comment: You will probably get better help using the [SWI-Prolog Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swi-prolog) Jan hangs out there and almost daily answers some specific questions.

Comment: @GuyCoder I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and most of the issues were fixed. I installed 7.6.4 again and uninstalled it using the "Uninstall Only" executable instead of the regular one (?) and it actually removed the SWIPL folder from my Program Files folder, which was good. I noticed that while it was installed, all PCE Emacs behavior seemed back to normal. I reinstalled 8.0.1 and there haven't been any weird errors or anything so far, but syntax highlighting, etc. still just doesn't work...